# Как писать Makefile для сборки модулей ядра

Tags: linux, kernel, makefile

Помогите разобраться в том, как пишется мейкфайл для сборки модуля ядра для линукс. У меня есть такой `Makefile`:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

- для чего нужно obj-m?
- make -C это переход в директорию. А для чего нужна директория build в конце пути?
- M=$(PWD) К чему относится M? Это переменная  или ключ команды? Где определяется $(PWD) и какое значение у этой переменной?
- Что такое modules и clean в конце первой и второй команды?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276326/7286264 -- похоже на ответ прямо для вашего случая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу кратко:

1. obj-m - переменная утилиты make, сборочные скрипты ядра, вызываемые перечисленными командами, берут из неё имена модулей(имена файлов с исходными кодами) из которых будет собран модуль ядра.
2. Это указание утилите make текущего каталога где искать Makefile, соответственно build - это конечное место сборки.
3. M - переменная окружения, указывает сборочным скриптам ядра, где находятся ваши исходные коды и куда поместить результат сборки. По умолчанию, результат может оказаться в текущей директории.
4. modules, clean - tragets - цели сборки, утилита make ищет все перечисленные цели в текущем Makefile (в данном случае в папке указанной через опцию -C), и выполняет перечисленные там правила сборки.

Для расширения познание, рекомендую погуглить правила написания Makefile, тогда многое стане понятнее.